# wso2-am 2.0.0: "Error occurred while executing the action generateApplicationKey"

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm getting an error from the WSO2 API Manager Store when attempting to generate consumer key/secret pair.

[Screenshot: Error occurred while executing the action generateApplicationKey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mtyx.png)

The logs contain about 1200 lines of stack trace, parts of which seem to repeat.  Here's a representative sample:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-22 13:57:11,563] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl} -  Could not execute Workflow {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error occurred when updating the status of the Application creation process
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:82)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:54)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:2790)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:36)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_getApplicationKey(APIStoreHostObject.java:382)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c3._c_anonymous_2(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag:39)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c3.call(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0._c_anonymous_11(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag:38)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0.call(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:240)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.exec(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
  at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
  at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
  at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
  at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
  at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
  at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
  at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
  at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1749)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1708)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.handleException(APIUtil.java:1195)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:155)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:118)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:78)
  ... 72 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not create OAuth application  : DefaultApplication_PRODUCTION
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.handleException(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:636)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:110)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:139)
  ... 74 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:326)
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:196)
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:77)
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:451)
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:278)
  at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
  at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
  at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
  at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:2393)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:62)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:108)
  ... 75 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-22 13:57:11,569] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject} -  Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:DefaultApplication {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject}
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Could not execute Workflow
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:2815)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIConsumer.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(UserAwareAPIConsumer.java:36)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIStoreHostObject.jsFunction_getApplicationKey(APIStoreHostObject.java:382)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c3._c_anonymous_2(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag:39)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c3.call(/store/modules/subscription/key.jag)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0._c_anonymous_11(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag:38)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.subscription.c0.call(/store/modules/subscription/module.jag)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:240)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag:3)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
  at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.call(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
  at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.site.blocks.subscription.subscription_add.ajax.c0.exec(/store/site/blocks/subscription/subscription-add/ajax/subscription-add.jag)
  at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
  at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
  at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:588)
  at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:508)
  at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:747)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:377)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
  at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
  at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
  at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
  at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1749)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1708)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.WorkflowException: Error occurred when updating the status of the Application creation process
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:82)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.execute(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:54)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIConsumerImpl.requestApprovalForApplicationRegistration(APIConsumerImpl.java:2790)
  ... 70 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error occurred while executing SubscriberKeyMgtClient.
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.handleException(APIUtil.java:1195)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:155)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.generateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:118)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.complete(ApplicationRegistrationSimpleWorkflowExecutor.java:78)
  ... 72 more 
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Can not create OAuth application  : DefaultApplication_PRODUCTION
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.handleException(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:636)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:110)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.workflow.AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.dogenerateKeysForApplication(AbstractApplicationRegistrationWorkflowExecutor.java:139)
  ... 74 more
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.handleResponse(HTTPSender.java:326)
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:196)
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.send(HTTPSender.java:77)
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.writeMessageWithCommons(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:451)
  at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.CommonsHTTPTransportSender.invoke(CommonsHTTPTransportSender.java:278)
  at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
  at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
  at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
  at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.stub.subscriber.APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.createOAuthApplicationByApplicationInfo(APIKeyMgtSubscriberServiceStub.java:2393)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.client.SubscriberKeyMgtClient.createOAuthApplicationbyApplicationInfo(SubscriberKeyMgtClient.java:62)
  at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.createApplication(AMDefaultKeyManagerImpl.java:108)
  ... 75 more
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-09-22 13:57:11,574] ERROR {JAGGERY.site.blocks.subscription.subscription-add.ajax.subscription-add:jag} -  org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: Error while obtaining the application access token for the application:DefaultApplication {JAGGERY.site.blocks.subscription.subscription-add.ajax.subscription-add:jag}
```

The "401 Error: Unauthorized" seems like it might be the key, but I know my credentials are correct because I used them to log in.

What's particularly interesting is, I only get this error when I'm using my company's LDAP server as the primary user store.

Here's a snippet from my {server-home}/repository/conf/user-mgt.xml:

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager">
    <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://localhost:1389</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionName">CN=Steven McClellan,CN=Users,DC=Nanofluidics,DC=com</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionPassword">passwordgoeshere</Property>
    <Property name="UserSearchBase">CN=Users,DC=Nanofluidics,DC=com</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
    <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute"/>
    <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
    <Property name="GroupSearchBase">CN=Users,DC=Nanofluidics,DC=com</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=group)(cn=?))</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=group)</Property>
    <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
    <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">false</Property>
    <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,50}$</Property>
    <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,50}$</Property>
    <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,100}$</Property>
    <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
    <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
    <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
    <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
    <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
    <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">true</Property>
    <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
    <Property name="ReadTimeout"/>
    <Property name="RetryAttempts"/>
    <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
</UserStoreManager>
```

(Note that I'm connecting to the LDAP server via an ssh tunnel at localhost:1389)

When I instead configure to connect to the [test ldap server at forumsys.com](http://www.forumsys.com/en/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/), I'm able to generate application key/secret pairs successfully.  Here's a snippet of the user-mgt.xml for that setup:

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager">
    <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionName">cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionPassword">password</Property>
    <Property name="UserSearchBase">dc=example,dc=com</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameAttribute">cn</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(cn=?))</Property>
    <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
    <Property name="DisplayNameAttribute"/>
    <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
    <Property name="GroupSearchBase">dc=example,dc=com</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)(cn=?))</Property>
    <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfUniqueNames)</Property>
    <Property name="MembershipAttribute">uniqueMember</Property>
    <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">false</Property>
    <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="PasswordJavaRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
    <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
    <Property name="PasswordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
    <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
    <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
    <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
    <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
    <Property name="ConnectionPoolingEnabled">true</Property>
    <Property name="LDAPConnectionTimeout">5000</Property>
    <Property name="ReadTimeout"/>
    <Property name="RetryAttempts"/>
    <Property name="ReplaceEscapeCharactersAtUserLogin">true</Property>
</UserStoreManager>
```

Also noteworthy is the fact that this is the *only* operation that fails with this configuration. (That I'm aware of.) I'm able to log in to the /carbon, /publisher, and /store pages. I'm able to create, manage, publish, and subscribe to APIs. I'm able to create and manage users and roles. Etc., etc.

So I'm pretty confused. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do you have a separate key manager or is this a standalone node setup?

Comment: Nope, it's standalone.

Comment: In api-manager.xml do you have the default variables(${admin.username}, ${admin.password}) for username and password in APIKeyValidator configuration? If so, those variables will be evaluated from the Username/Password defined in user-mgt.xml.

Comment: Yes, this is what I have:

<AuthManager><ServerURL>https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services/</ServerURL>
<Username>${admin.username}</Username>
<Password>${admin.password}</Password>
<CheckPermissionsRemotely>false</CheckPermissionsRemotely>
</AuthManager>

Comment: How about the <APIKeyValidator> configuration there?

Comment: Same:

<APIKeyValidator>        <ServerURL>https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services/</ServerURL>
<Username>${admin.username}</Username>
<Password>${admin.password}</Password>
<KeyValidatorClientType>ThriftClient</KeyValidatorClientType>
<ThriftClientConnectionTimeOut>10000</ThriftClientConnectionTimeOut>
<EnableThriftServer>true</EnableThriftServer>
<ThriftServerHost>localhost</ThriftServerHost>        <KeyValidationHandlerClassName>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.DefaultKeyValidationHandler</KeyValidationHandlerClassName>
</APIKeyValidator>

Comment: The only configuration file I've modified from the installation defaults is the user-mgt.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same error and fixed by setting correct datasource at identity.xml at IS